# Why SQL Server FTS ignores some character?

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, special-characters, persian

I am using SQL Server 2012 Full Text Search.

I have a field in "categories" table that contains main keywords of categories and i am using a separator character such as "-" or "," for each keyword.

This is a Persian sample of data for keyword field:

Persian Sample:

> ,یراق الات پنجره,یراق الات درب و پنجره,یراق پنجره,

English Sample:

> ,door,entry door,yard door,

Now when i use this "Like" statement, the result is OK:

```
select * from  categories where  SiteSearchExactMacth like '%,درب,%'
select * from  categories where  SiteSearchExactMacth like '%,door,%'
```

But when i use FTS the result returns more than records of "Like" query and "," or "-" character will be ignored:

```
select * from  categories where contains( SiteSearchExactMacth ,N'",درب,"')
select * from  categories where contains( SiteSearchExactMacth ,N'",door,"')
```

How can i use Full Text Search for this case?

Comment: Check your `COLLATE` value `COLLATE Persian_100_BIN` in database/table level

Comment: Yes.I changed my collate with values  `COLLATE Persian_100_BIN` and `COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AI` but result not changed.